# How to create my own command in linux

Tags: linux

I wrote a simple cpp code by using vi. I want to use cat command inside this program (by using execl and it will take my file as argument). I also have to write my own command. For example it will work like that: $mycommand filename. And cat command which is inside my cpp code will show my cpp file's content. I'm new so I don't know how to do it. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**1) Redirecting output** 

The output of the cat command should go to the standard output of your program.
For this your program should pass its standard output FD to the exec command. This will be the default case. So you don't have to do anything extra.

**2) cat on the source file** 

Now, the cat thing : "And cat command which is inside my cpp code will show my cpp file's content. " This statement does not explain your need. If you want the cat of the executable you are running, you can do an objdump on your executable. The executable path can be found out from the proc file system with your pid. For a generic case, it does not matter whether the file is a cpp file or not.

**3) making command** 

To make your executable run as a standard command on a terminal, you must add the directory containing the executable to the PATH directories list. You can do so by adding your executable to /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin. (Convention is that it should go in /usr/local/bin since it has been compiled locally). If you don't have administrator privileges on the machine, you must append the source directory to the PATH directory list.

Comment: I done the first parts but I couldn't figure out how to add my executable to /usr/local/bin

Comment: adding executable to /usr/local/bin means to copy the a.out to the folder /usr/local/bin. cmd : cp a.out /usr/local/bin. Replace a.out with your executable name. One more thing : cp wont work straightaway since you must have write privileges to /usr/local/bin. So give your command as sudo.